# Does the most significant bit of a Two's Complement number indicate its sign?

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I was converting -15 to Two's complement -

15 in binary = 1111

Flip bits and add 1 = 0001

However I also thought that the leftmost digit of a two's complement number indicates whether it represents a positive (0) or negative (1) number? Need some help understanding this

Comment: Q: what is the range you can represent with 4 bits in two's complement representation?

Comment: -8 (1000) to 7 (0111). Does this mean the flip bits and add one would apply to 01111 making it (10000 + 1) = 10001?